# Aligning name and speech vertically

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm working on a class for making meeting minutes. I want my page to contain the name of the speaker in the left column, and the actual speech of the speaker in the right column. The name of speaker and the speech should be top aligned.

The goal is to get a class in which if the speakers name does not fit on a single line in the left column, it should continue on the next line. If the speech does not fit on the current page entirely, it should continue on the next page. And the first line of the speakers name and the first line of his speech should be vertically aligned

If first had this, however this breaks for pages breaks and speeches that are too long to fit on a single page

```
\newcommand{\opmerking}[2]{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\leftcolumnwidth}
        #1 % name of speaker
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{\columngapwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\rightcolumnwidth}
        #2 % speech
    \end{minipage}\medskip
}
```

I then tried this, but this breaks for names that do not fit on a single line in the left column:

```
\newcommand{\opmerking}[2]{
\parbox[\leftcolumnwidth][t]{#1}
\begin{adjustwidth}{\leftcolumnwidth+\columngapwidth}{}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}% Align name of speaker and environment
    #2
\end{adjustwidth}\medskip
}
```

Finally I tried using the tcolorbox package, this seemed to work. However I could not manage to vertically align the title and the box s.t. the name of the speaker and the speech are aligned.

Anyone who knows how to achieve this using LaTeX?

Picture to clarify:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Are you aware of the [minutes package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minutes/)?

Comment: question is not that clear but perhaps you are looking for `\raggedright#1 % name of speaker`

Comment: @marmot I checked it out but sadly does not achieve what i want

Comment: Can we assume the “speaker” box is just one line high?

Comment: @egreg No that is the hard part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution may be to use the [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol/) package. The following MWE is not very elaborate, it is only intended to demonstrate the general idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\speech}[2]{\switchcolumn[0]*{\noindent\raggedright #1}\switchcolumn[1]#2}
\columnratio{0.2}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\speech{First speaker}{\lipsum[1]}

\speech{Second\\speaker}{\lipsum[2]\par\lipsum[3]}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

It gives the following result.

[image: Output of the MWE]